# How to deduplicate in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have a Presto table assume it has [id, name, update_time] columns and data

```
(1, Amy, 2018-08-01),
(1, Amy, 2018-08-02),
(1, Amyyyyyyy, 2018-08-03),
(2, Bob, 2018-08-01)
```

Now, I want to execute a sql and the result will be

```
(1, Amyyyyyyy, 2018-08-03),
(2, Bob, 2018-08-01)
```

Currently, my best way to deduplicate in Presto is below.

```
select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.name,
    t1.update_time 
from table_name t1
join (select id, max(update_time) as update_time from table_name group by id) t2
    on t1.id = t2.id and t1.update_time = t2.update_time
```

More information, clike [deduplication in sql](http://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=fc13cbac5a4df6df599fd14cbf590fa5&sub=9477488FA55C4C39BB79AFE3B08A499E)

Is there a better way to deduplicate in Presto?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In PrestoDB, I would be inclined to use `row_number()`:

```
select id, name, date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) as seqnum
      from table_name t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: That is what I wanted! Your sql did good performance: less input data but more cpu and memory. I noted that in [note](https://note.youdao.com/share/?id=fc13cbac5a4df6df599fd14cbf590fa5&type=note#/)

Answer (score 1):

You seems want `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where update_time = (select MAX(t1.update_time) from table t1 where t1.id = t.id);
```

Comment: It did better than my sql(way 1) and I add to my note, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way

```
WITH latestDate AS (SELECT id,max(date) as latestDate FROM table_name GROUP BY id)
    SELECT id,name,date FROM table_name t INNER JOIN latestDate l ON t.id = l.id AND t.date = l.latestDate
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy:

```
Select id, name, MAX(update_time) as [Last Update] from table_name Group by id
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's my fault that not describe my question clearly. And I already edited my question. Please check. Thank for your help.

Comment: @AlexGum in my code i only need to remove the column `Name` from the `Group by` clause (i did that edit already), the other code that @Yogesh Sharma suggested should work too

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it. but in Presto sql, column in `SELECT` clause must in `GROUP BY` clause, not like MySql. The answer from Gordon Linoff is really "Presto" style. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

just use `in` operator

```
 select t.*
    from tableA t
    where update_time in (select MAX(tableA.update_time) from tableA goup by id)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, it will also show the row `(1, Amy, 2018-08-01)` because the date `2018-08-01` is the max for the id = 2, you can try it and see, my english is not good enough to explain it well!

Comment: @TonnerMààn no you are wrong because i consider only id not name

Comment: it's the column update_time where there is the issue, i ran a test just to be sure and the resaults are as i expected, i'm sorry my english is not very good that's why i didn't know how to explain my idea

Comment: I think @TonnerMààn is right, I had  try it. The answer GordonLinoff and YogeshSharma given has the best performance for now. I noted them in  [click](https://note.youdao.com/share/?id=fc13cbac5a4df6df599fd14cbf590fa5&type=note#/)