# How to deduplicate in Presto SQL without with only varchar data

Tags: sql, presto

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630164/how-to-deduplicate-in-presto). However, I have only `varchar` data so I can't use the solutions there. My data looks like this:

```
id   | activity | type
------------------------
al12 |  a1a4    | MOVE
la23 |  2a5e    | WAIT
la23 |  2a5e    | WAIT
ie42 |  35a8    | STAY
```

The third row is a duplicate. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, activity, type
FROM your_table
```

https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/sql/select.html